# Procedure Passes Null Values on inserting and Update ASPXgridview

Tags: sql, asp.net, sql-server, stored-procedures, aspxgridview

I wrote a procedure as follows

```
USE [Farm_Project]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[prod1_insert]    Script Date: 11/12/2014 1:21:20 PM      ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER proc [dbo].[prod1_insert]
(
  @coop_id int,
  @good_eggs int=0,
  @broken_eggs int=0,
  @small_eggs int= 0,
  @date smalldatetime=null

  )
  AS
  if @date is null
  set @date=getdate()

  insert into Prod1 (cc_id,  gd_Eggs,   br_Eggs,   sm_Eggs,  Prod_date  )
  values
                  (@coop_id  ,@good_eggs,  @broken_eggs, @small_eggs,@date)
```

Then I use the procedure as an Insert Query for ASPX Gridview (DEV Express)

Also I have a similar procedure for insert.

But in both cases all values I enter are being passed as Null and I get an Error "Cannot insert Null for Column CC_ID", and by using SQL Server Pofiler I found out that all values are being sent to SQL server as 'null'. Please help I have tried all that I know.

Thank you in advance.

```
  <dx:GridViewCommandColumn ShowDeleteButton="True" ShowEditButton="True" ShowNewButtonInHeader="True" VisibleIndex="0">
        </dx:GridViewCommandColumn>
        <dx:GridViewDataTextColumn FieldName="prod_ID" ReadOnly="True" VisibleIndex="1">
            <EditFormSettings Visible="False" />
        </dx:GridViewDataTextColumn>
        <dx:GridViewDataTextColumn FieldName="cc_id" VisibleIndex="2">
        </dx:GridViewDataTextColumn>
        <dx:GridViewDataTextColumn FieldName="gd_Eggs" VisibleIndex="3">
        </dx:GridViewDataTextColumn>
        <dx:GridViewDataTextColumn FieldName="br_Eggs" VisibleIndex="4">
        </dx:GridViewDataTextColumn>
        <dx:GridViewDataTextColumn FieldName="sm_Eggs" VisibleIndex="5">
        </dx:GridViewDataTextColumn>
        <dx:GridViewDataTextColumn FieldName="Total" ReadOnly="True" VisibleIndex="6">
            <EditFormSettings Visible="False" />
        </dx:GridViewDataTextColumn>
        <dx:GridViewDataTextColumn FieldName="Trays" ReadOnly="True" VisibleIndex="7">
            <EditFormSettings Visible="False" />
        </dx:GridViewDataTextColumn>
        <dx:GridViewDataTextColumn FieldName="Eggs_xtra" ReadOnly="True" VisibleIndex="8">
            <EditFormSettings Visible="False" />
        </dx:GridViewDataTextColumn>
        <dx:GridViewDataDateColumn FieldName="Prod_date" VisibleIndex="9">
        </dx:GridViewDataDateColumn>
    </Columns>
</dx:ASPxGridView>
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="prodSource" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:Farm_ProjectConnectionString %>" DeleteCommand="prod1_delete" 
    InsertCommand="prod1_insert" 
    SelectCommand="prod1_select"
     UpdateCommand="prod1_update"
     DeleteCommandType="StoredProcedure" 
    InsertCommandType="StoredProcedure" 
    OnInserted="prodSource_Inserted" 
    SelectCommandType="StoredProcedure" 
    UpdateCommandType="StoredProcedure">
    <DeleteParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Name="prod_id" />
    </DeleteParameters>
    <InsertParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Name="coop_id" Type="Int32" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="good_eggs" Type="Int32" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="broken_eggs" Type="Int32" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="small_eggs" Type="Int32" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="date" Type="DateTime" />
    </InsertParameters>
    <UpdateParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Name="prod_ID" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="code" Type="Int32" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="good_eggs" Type="Int32" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="broken_eggs" Type="Int32" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="small_eggs" Type="Int32" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="date" Type="DateTime" />
    </UpdateParameters>
```

Comment: this is the Error in ASP .net while inserting                 Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'cc_id', table 'Farm_Project.dbo.Prod1'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.
The statement has been terminated.

Comment: Actually the SP works correctly but the values send from aspx are null. Then why you post the SP??

Comment: yes the SP works quite well , how do I solve the Null Values problem. because I do put values in but still I get Null and the Statement is terminated

Comment: your procedure throws exception or not???

Comment: please show the code that calls the stored procedure otherwise it's impossible to see where the issue might be

Comment: @Tanner please look at the edited post

Comment: @HardikParmar I get no exception thrown, and the procedure works fine in SQL server itself. but in the front end there is a problem with the values

Comment: so I solved my problem , but I am left with questions, here is how I solved it : in the procedure I used as a select statement I removed Column ALIAS names also in the parameter names I had to use exact column name, thus I was able to insert ,update ,delete and select with no problem. my New Question is why did ALIASes bring this problem , I thought it was supposed to be used in this way .  like SELECT CC_ID AS COOP  and also in parameter name  create proc prod1_insert ( @coop int ) . why did this problem occur